# Regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to match this regexp in javascript:

```
com\..*</div>
```

As you can see I want to have com. and then anything and then `</div>`.
But in javascript this is not working, it always founds the `com/jdksf</div>` not the `com.fdsfd<div>` text.
Any idea why is that?

---

Edit:
My code looks like this:

```
var patt1=new RegExp("com\..*</div>");
alert(patt1.exec(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML));
```

Comment: Post your actual code please - can't tell anything from such a short description.

Comment: The code you included in your edit doesn't have any \escape characters at all

Comment: Added, I used this \escape, but it isn't working

Comment: you need a double escape because it's a string, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`, like this:

```
var patt1=new RegExp("com\\..*</div>");
```

The double backslash is because it's a string, so `\\.` is really `\.` in the regex.  Or, declare it as a regex object directly:

```
var patt1 = /com\..*<\/div>/;
```

[You can test both versions here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qDcuh/).

Comment: won't solve the problem though - '.' matches anything, including the literal '.' character.

Comment: @Benubird - this is escaping it, so it's `\.` in the end, which is a literal match.

Comment: Right, what I meant was, if it's not matching com.foo with com..*, changing it to con\..* won't help - but I see I misread the question, your solution is correct in this case. +1

Comment: I think this will be ok, I just have some problem, hold on, I try to resolve it.

Comment: Does it matter if I have a line break before the `</div>`. I don't think so.